# Open a html file inside a zip file. Python 3.6. TypeError: 'ZipFile' object is not callable.

Tags: html, python-3.x, zip

I am learning about python and I want to open a html file inside a zip file. I'm reading tutorials and following documentation I found online for python 3.6 but I can't print the content of the news.html document which is inside the John.zip folder

```
import zipfile


file = zipfile.ZipFile("John.zip", "r")


with file('John.zip') as myzip:
    with myzip.open("news.html") as myfile:
        print(myfile.read())
```

When I start without debugging it shows "TypeError: 'ZipFile' object is not callable

But I can't fix this. I tried simpler things such as trying to open it the way you open a .txt file

```
file=open("John.zip/news.html")
print(file.read())
```

this didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is storing a ZipFile as an object named it "file". Then, in the line beginning with "with", you're calling it as if it were a function. That is why you received the TypeError, because that object you named "file" is not a callable function.

Get rid of the line where you stored it as "file", and try something like this:
`with zipfile.ZipFile('John.zip', 'r') as myzip:`

Source:
Python Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects

Comment: Updated it to use your import.

Comment: I did what you mentioned but this time I get an error saying :There is not item name 'news.html' in the archive"

Comment: Hard to gather what is wrong since I don't know what is in your zip file, but is the file actually there? Is it actually named "news.html" and not "news.htm"?

Comment: yes, there is that file and there is about 5 more files with different names. all of them html,thank you for trying to help me

Comment: Could you try this for me?  

print(ZipFile.namelist())

below the first with. This should print the contents of the zip so you can see what Python sees. Sorry for the edits.

Comment: I tried and it said ZipFile is not defined. However I had tried this before:   
    for content in file.namelist():           
    print (content)
    print()                                                                                                                  and it does show all the file names inside the John.zip folder, this worked when I was using the line you asked me to erase though.     
One question, when you said "get ride of the line where you stored it as "file"" you meant the line:   file = zipfile.ZipFile("John.zip", "r")   correct?

Comment: Yeah my mistake, I originally as going to list the function inside of ZipFile, what I should have asked you to do was: `print(myzip.namelist())`. Yes, I meant for you to get rid of that line as you aren't referencing it using the `with` line I originally suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have overridden the builtin function "file" by setting the global variable "file".
just print the file see whats in it.

Answer (score 0):

[TypeError: 'ZipFile' object is not callable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nclp1.png)
I had the similar problem, in my case i was working on google colab and i was getting this error but i updated the tensorflow version to v2.0.0 from v1.5.0 and it worked.

If the problem is not resoöved even after updatíng the tensorflow then try update to higher python version or lower python version sometimes, hope it would be solved.